# how to use hover images with twitter bootstrap dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, css, hover, twitter-bootstrap

Using twitter bootstrap.  on the site i have a top nav bar consisting of links where some have dd-menus, and some are just static links.

i'm constructing the links using img's instead of text anchors.

i would like to get a hover effect applied to each of the links in the nav bar. this to be done by swapping out the image or loading a different background location in the sprite.

i'm using the regular way of specifying the nav bar,

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
         <li class="dropdown" id="hifiMenu">
               <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#hifiMenu"><img src="$PRE/images/newhifi.png"></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li class="mainitem"><a href="$PRE/newhifi">BY BRAND</a></li>
```

is it possible to put a hover on the A link for #hifiMenu, and when the dropdown is activated, have the image swapped out?

not quite sure what the best practice would be using TB's nav bar control.  has anyone tried something like this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use a background image inside a span tag? Replacing an `img` image on hover sounds like a lot of work that can be easily accomplished with a background-image.

Comment: @Andres thanks! yeah, i think that would work just fine. i ended up making it work by assigning an ID to each of the anchors and setting a background for each of the `#linkID {}` and a `#linkID:hover {}`.  i also used [spriteme.com](http://www.spriteme.com/) to help create a main sprite image.

Comment: Dan, can you post your results in the form of an answer and approve it? This way it will help future users with the same questions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in my question, i have the following nav bar items:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
     <li class="dropdown" id="hifiMenu">
           <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#hifiMenu"><img src="newhifi.png"></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li class="mainitem"><a href="newhifi">BY BRAND</a></li>
....
```

in order to get the hover to work, i first created a large sprite image that contained every normal/highlighted image.

then i set up a new style for each of my links:

```
#hifiMenuLink {
    width:71px;
    height: 11px;
    background-image: url(path_to_sprite);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -6px;
}
```

then for the hover:

```
#hifiMenuLink:hover {
    width:71px;
    height: 11px;
    background-image: url(path_to_sprite);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -37px;
}
```

then i assigned the ID, hifiMenuLink, to the anchor itself...

```
<a id="hifiMenuLink" ...
```

that was my quick and dirty solution.

hope this can help out someone else in the future.